# Getter/setter of a vector

Tags: arrays, vector

```
public class Practica2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {  

Vector v = new Vector(3); //create an empty Vector vec with an initial capacity of 3   
v.setpos(0,1); //set 0 at 1 index position
v.setpos(1,2); //set 1 at 2 index position
v.setpos(3,3); //set 3 at 3 index position
v.print();
```

This is my class Vector:

```
package practica2;
public class Vector {
//Atributes
private double[] values;
private int dim;

//Methods 
public Vector(int dim) {
    this.dim = dim;

}

public void setpos(int i, int value) {
    values[i] = value;


}

public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= dim; i++) {
        System.out.println(values);


    }
```

I get this error and i dont know how to fix it, I just wasted 2 hours, i'm new in Java.

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at practica2.Vector.setpos(Vector.java:24)
    at practica2.Practica2.main(Practica2.java:23)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A null pointer exception occurs in java when you try to use an object without first initializing it. You never initialize the `values` array. Add this into your constructor (I'm assuming that you wanted it to be length dim:

```
values = new double[dim];
```

That will fix one error, and probably give you an array index out of bounds error. In java, arrays are 0-indexed. That is, if you have an array of length 3, the valid indeces of that array are 0, 1, and 2. NOT 3. You should change

```
v.setpos(3,3);
```

to

```
v.setpos(2,3);
```

You are also calling `println(values)` which prints using the Array's toString() method (basically, it's garbage). You'll want to change the print statement to `System.out.println(values[i])`

Now your program should run correctly.

As a side note, you dont have to save the value of `dim`. You can use instead `values.length`. (In your print method, for example).

Comment: Thanks! I didnt noticed that values where not inicializated in my contruct. I changed too the v.setpos. I run now my code and I get this: run: [D@4ffe0816 [D@4ffe0816 [D@4ffe0816 [D@4ffe0816 i dont know why :/

Comment: What I want my code do is: Create a new java class named: Vector -The constructor having as parameter the dimension of the vector -element getter and setters -A print operation And i need to run my code with this main:    Vector v = new Vector ( 3 ) ; v.set(0,1); v.set(1,2); v.set(2,3); v.print();v.print();

Comment: great, this starts to work properly, but i still got this run:
1.0
2.0
3.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at practica2.Vector.print(Vector.java:33)
 at practica2.Practica2.main(Practica2.java:26)
Java Result: 1

Comment: thanks for all, i'm new here, but if i can give u some kind of approval or reputation, just tell me how.

Comment: @user2969143 The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException would only occur if you are calling setPos with the first argument >= dim. You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it under the number. Thanks!